# allowing others access to specified subdirectories only

Tags: linux, chmod

I have some folders with pictures and videos that I would like my other family members be able to view. I have added these folders to the family group, like this:

```
chgrp -R family shared_pictures/
```

The group permissions are set to +rx for the folders and +r for the files inside the folders. The family members have already been added to the family group. However when they try to access the folders/files, they get a "operation not permitted error". I think it has to do with the fact that the permssions of my my home folder are set like this:

```
drwxr-x--- 163 mario mario 12288 2012-03-21 07:50 /home/mario
```

So 'other' users have no permissions at all (no directory content viewing, etc).

My question: is it possible to allow access to some subdirectories only and leave my home directory permissions as is? Or is my only option to open my home directory up for others with +rx? (because when I do this it works, but now anyone can view the contents in my home dir, which is not what I want)

Comment: You might want to look at [`bindfs`](http://code.google.com/p/bindfs/).

Comment: folders must have the r and x bit to access them. The x bit for folders does not mean execute but means you are able to access the folder.

Comment: You need to set "x" bit (o+x) for all parent directories. Do not add "r" bit which let them browse your directory contents

Comment: @Cougar I think this might be what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Create the directory somewhere else (/opt/, for example) and link it symbolically into your home for convenience.

Comment: Creating user data directories under /opt would be against FHS.

Comment: @l1zard: And what does the FHS suggest?